# How to perform both read and write operations with fstream?

Tags: c++, file, debugging, fstream

I'm writing a program to write data to a file. The function creating the issue boils down to

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    std::fstream file_to_read("mydata.data");
    std::string header_line;

    std::getline(file_to_read, header_line);

    file_to_read.write("test", 5);
```

Obviously I have code that ensures the file is open first. But the issue is: the file remains empty after running the program. If I remove the std::getline call, it works.  Is there a way to have both reading and writing work in this situation?

Comment: An fstream only has a single file position, for either read or write. To change mode, you have to do a seek when altering between read and write. See [seekg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and [seekp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)

Comment: It is normal to read from one file and write to another.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to read _and_ write from/to the same file.

Comment: @PaulSanders The first line is a header that dictates the format the data should be written in.

Comment: And do you want to keep that line?  We need a clear statement of your requirements here.  Like I say, if you have a file that tells your program what you want it to do, you wouldn't normally overwrite it.

Comment: Yes. I do not want to overwrite that line. I want to read the line. Set output stream position to the next line after, and start writing. I think I can figure out how to do that using seekg/p and tellg/p.

Comment: OK, that should work